# setMargins to relative layout not working in Grid layout

Tags: android

```
 GridLayout glSameLoactions;
@OnClick(R.id.tvAddLocation)
void addLocationOnClickListener(){
    if(i==0) {
        glSameLoactions = new GridLayout(this);
        glSameLoactions.setColumnCount(3);
        glSameLoactions.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_rounded_corner_blurfilled);
        glSameLoactions.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
    }
    RelativeLayout rlLocation = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rlLocation.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,200);
    relativeParams.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);//<<<<----- NOT WORKING
    rlLocation.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
    rlLocation.requestLayout();
    rlLocation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_rounded_corner_blurfilled);

    TextView tvLocationName = new TextView(this);
    tvLocationName.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvLocationName.setId(R.id.tvLocationName);
    tvLocationName.setText("amritsar,PB");
    tvLocationName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    tvLocationName.setTextSize(14f);

    ImageView ivRadiobtn = new ImageView(this);
    tvLocationName.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ivRadiobtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_circle_empty);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    rlLocation.addView(tvLocationName);
    rlLocation.addView(ivRadiobtn,lp);
    glSameLoactions.addView(rlLocation);
if (i==0) {
llLocations.addView(glSameLoactions);
llLocations.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    i++;

}
```

I am making a layout programmatically, in which on a click of button, a new relative layout is added in a grid layout. All my code is working fine, but the problem is that i am unable to set margins to the relative layout inside the grid layout. Please help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300); 
relativeParams.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);
rlLocation.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```